# How to create a very basic 'plugin'?

Tags: javascript

[Fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/HedNP/)

I am trying to create a very basic 'plugin', if you can even call this that. I want to be able to use this line `var box = new colorBox(node, options);` (at the end of the JS) in order to edit the style of `div#thing1`. I think my problem is invoking the functions I have set up. I do not want to have to call `colorBox.setSize()` to have an initial effect, but i want to be able to call it later if i want after the object of colorBox prototype is set up. Thanks!

HTML:

```
<div id="thing1"></div>
<div id="thing2"></div>
```

JS:

```
var colorBox = {
    setSize: function(){
        node.style.width = options.width + 'px';
        node.style.height = options.height + 'px';
    },
    setColor: function(){
        node.style.backgroundColor = options.color;
    },
    setSize(),
    setColor()
}

var node = document.getElementById('thing1');
var options = {
    color: 'red',
    width: 200,
    height: 200
}

var box = new colorBox(node, options);
```

Comment: What's the question here?

Comment: What do you mean by Plugin? Do you mean Object instead? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object if so, have a look for the constructor

Comment: "I do not want to have to call colorBox.setSize() to have an initial effect" Why not?

Comment: @AlexWayne bc most plugins dont work that way, and i want to learn good practices, plus i already know how to do that.

Comment: @sherlock It's hard to talk about good practices without the right terminology.  "plugin" Doesn't mean anything in the javascript world unless your talking about jQuery specifically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new object using a constructor function:

```
var colorBox = function(node, options) {
    this.setSize = function(){
        node.style.width = options.width + 'px';
        node.style.height = options.height + 'px';
    };
    this.setColor = function(){
        node.style.backgroundColor = options.color;
    };
    this.setSize();
    this.setColor();
}

var node = document.getElementById('thing1');
var options = {
    color: 'red',
    width: 200,
    height: 200
}

var box = new colorBox(node, options);
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e7gX8/1/

Comment: Yeah this was a fun one because the answer was exactly what you were looking to do :-)

Comment: its strange logic to me, bc basically you just put 'this' in front of everything i already had. i guess thats what makes it a prototype??

Comment: the `this`s are not actually needed in this example (try it without them) - but will be useful if you want to be able to adjust the colorBox later in the programme, e.g. `colorBox.setSize(10)`

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a constructor function to set the values you were passing. Here's how you can do this :

```
var colorBox = function(node, options) {
    this.setSize = function(){
        node.style.width = options.width + 'px';
        node.style.height = options.height + 'px';
    };

    this.setColor = function(){
        node.style.backgroundColor = options.color;
    };
    this.setSize();
    this.setColor();
}
```

[Try in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HedNP/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up different ways of making objects in javascript. What you want is probably the way in Lyn Headley's answer. This is the other way (or rather one of the other ways), which would also work but is needlessly complicated and would only allow you to have a single `colorBox` (but it might be useful to know for other situations).

```
var colorBox = {
    setSize: function(){
        this.node.style.width = this.options.width + 'px';
        this.node.style.height = this.options.height + 'px';
    },
    setColor: function(){
        this.node.style.backgroundColor = this.options.color;
    },
    initialize: function(node, options) {
        this.node = node;
        this.options = options;
        this.setSize();
        this.setColor();
    }
}

var node = document.getElementById('thing1');
var options = {
    color: 'red',
    width: 200,
    height: 200
}
colorBox.initialize(node, options);
```